# Snowflake procedure fail from task execution

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

The following error message is logged when running the procedure from a task, but works fine when I run it manually:

> Execution error in store procedure STAGE_SERVICEBUS_ORDER: "Query
>   code" missing from JSON response At Statement.execute, line 4 position
>   60.

the procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "STAGE_SERVICEBUS_ORDER"(YEARMONTH VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '
 snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: `Truncate table DM.STG.SERVICEBUS_ORDER`}).execute();
 var copy_into_statement = `copy into DM.STG.SERVICEBUS_ORDER  (FILE_NAME,OBJECT)  from ( select metadata$filename, $1 from @SERVICEBUS_ORDER`+YEARMONTH+` )  file_format = (type = ''JSON'' strip_outer_array = false) force=true ON_ERROR = CONTINUE `;
 snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: copy_into_statement}).execute();
return ''Done'';
';
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. According to Snowflake support, it was a bug that they introduced in a newer release that they plan to address in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing `$1` with `PARSE_JSON($1)`.

Here's an example from Snowflake docs illustrating this solution for accessing JSON file metadata in a COPY statement:

```
-- Create a file format
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_json_format
  TYPE = 'json';

-- Create an internal stage
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE mystage2
  FILE_FORMAT = my_json_format;

-- Stage a data file
PUT file:///tmp/data1.json @mystage2;

-- Query the filename and row number metadata columns 
-- and the regular data columns in the staged file
SELECT METADATA$FILENAME, METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER, parse_json($1) 
FROM @mystage2/data1.json.gz;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html#example-2-querying-the-metadata-columns-for-a-json-file